# Getting limited answers using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

I have a RDF store with list of people and the cities/states they've lived in:

```
:P1 :hasLivedIn :NewYork

:P2 :hasLivedIn :NewYork
:P2 :hasLivedIn :California
```

Now, I'd like to use SPARQL to give me a list of all people who have lived in a particular city (e.g. newYork)

When I use this:

```
select * where { ?p :hasLivedIn :NewYork }
```

gives me both :P1 and :P2 but I only want :P1 because only :P1 has lived in *only* :NewYork.

I can't blacklist the cities using a filter because the cities and states are too many. Is there a way to do this in SPARQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative query to the one provided by @YMomb uses negation SPARQL 1.1:

```
SELECT  ?p
WHERE
  { ?p  :hasLivedIn  :NewYork
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?p  :hasLivedIn  ?place
                        FILTER ( ?place != :NewYork )
                      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably count the number of location where `?p` has lived in. And only output `?p` when it lived in only one, i.e. `:NewYork`

```
SELECT ?p WHERE {
     ?p :hasLivedIn :NewYork . 
     ?p :hasLivedIn ?anywhere
}
GROUP BY ?p
HAVING (COUNT(?anywhere) == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP_HAVING` answer is good.

It can also be done with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT ?p WHERE {
     ?p :hasLivedIn :NewYork .
     FILTER NOT EXISTS 
        { ?p :hasLivedIn ?anywhere. FILTER(?anywhere != :NewYork) }
}
```